# 'P 0' < 'P! ' in python and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

A script in Python didn't work, and I reduced the problem to what follows.

In PostgreSQL 9.1 I tried:

```
SELECT 'P 0' < 'P! '
f
```

And in Python 2.7.3:

```
>>> 'P 0' < 'P! '
True
```

Why is `' '` not lower than `'!'` in PostgreSQL?  What is happening?

Comment: Check what locale your database is using. String comparisons depend on how collation is done in the current locale.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not because of locale.

Comment: @KennyTM: Some locales ignore spaces when collating, which would explain the difference in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL is using your locale's collation rules for string comparison. Python is using a different locale (possibly "C") for collation.

It's hard to say more without knowing what your database `LC_COLLATE` is (from `\l+` in `psql`) and what your runtime environment for Python is. Try showing the database locale and the output of the shell `locale` command.

See [the PostgreSQL documentation on locales](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html).

For example, compare and contrast:

```
-- results may vary depending on your OS/libc
SELECT 'P 0' < 'P! ' COLLATE "C"; -- returns true
SELECT 'P 0' < 'P! ' COLLATE "en_GB"; -- returns false
```

Comment: LC_COLLATE = 'es_CL.UTF-8' in postgresql and LC_COLLATE="es_MX.UTF-8" in the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can never assume that the string comparison rules are the same in two different languages or systems. There are a myriad of conventions; it's not well-defined like it is with numbers.  Equality is the best-defined, but even there you find differences (trailing spaces being ignored, case not mattering, etc.); the specific ordering of unequal strings is way outside the realm of the portable.